# How to create a queue in ATS?

Tags: ats

I can use a list like a stack, but what is a proper way to create a queue in ATS? For instance, say I have the following pseudo code:

```
val xs = queue_create()
val () = xs.enqueue(1)
val () = xs.enqueue(2)
val () = print(xs.dequeue()) // print 1
val () = xs.enqueue(3)
val () = print(xs.dequeue()) // print 2
val () = print(xs.dequeue()) // print 3
```

I should see that 1, 2, and 3 are printed out.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm unaware of a queue type built in the ATS standard library, I offer my own basic implementation from one of my projects, adapted from the code referenced in the [*Linear Channels for Asynchronous IPC*](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/INT2PROGINATS/HTML/x4379.html) chapter of the *Introduction to Programming in ATS* book.

See a working example in [this snippet](https://glot.io/snippets/ejp5n09ghm).

Answer (score 0):

You could go the long-winded way: by using two pointers to head and tail of a singly-linked list.

However, ensuring that this implementation actually works is not so trivial. It relies on data views to encode certain invariants, and so is quite complex, but the outwards-facing API is not hard to use, at all. I've also used "intrusive" linked lists, to make things simpler for the use-case.

The core definitions are as follows:

View for encoding singly-linked list segments: a segment is just a singly-linked where the "last" `next` pointer can point anywhere, including to `NULL`:

```
dataview slseg_v
  (addr(*self*), addr(*last node's [next]*), int(*segment length*)) =
  | {n:nat} {l1,l2,l3:addr}
    slseg_v_cons (l1, l3, n+1) of (
      mfree_gc_v (l1), slseg_node_v (l2, l1), slseg_v (l2, l3, n)
    ) // end of [slseg_v_cons]
  | {l:addr} slseg_v_nil (l, l, 0)
// end of [slseg_v]
```

Type for a list-based queue: it is either empty, or contains a size, a pointer to head of segment, and a pointer to tail of segment:

```
datavtype queuelst_vt (int) =
  | {n:nat} {l1,l2,l3:addr}
    queuelst_vt_some (n+1) of (
      slseg_v (l1, l2, n),
      mfree_gc_v (l2),
      slseg_node_v (null, l2)
    | int n, ptr l1, ptr l2
    ) // end of [queuelst_vt_some]
  | queuelst_vt_none (0) of ()
```

You can run the full code at [Glot.io](https://glot.io/snippets/ejq8uss7h3)

Here's a bit cleaned up version of the same [code](https://glot.io/snippets/ejrcpfh1kj) -- this time, I tried to ensure that the code has clean interface/implementation separation.